# Creating my own function that mimics KeyFreeQ

Tags: function-construction

I want to create my own function `KeyFreeQ` using Mathematica's functions as little as possible.

For example:
I already have my own function `FreeQ`:

```
meuFreeQ // ClearAll
meuFreeQ[{n_, y___}, n_] := False;
meuFreeQ[{x_, y___}, n_] := meuFreeQ[{y}, n];
meuFreeQ[{}, n_] := True;
```

How can I do the same for `KeyFreeQ`?

Comment: Some pointers: There is no reason to use `CiearAll` when you do not give a function attributes. There is no reason to use `SetDelayed` when the righthand side is a constant.

Comment: Your version does not work correctly: `FreeQ[{{1}}, 1] =!= meuFreeQ[{{1}}, 1]`. Is this your code? Because I am not sure why are you stuck at `KeyFreeQ` if you already did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is straightforward:

```
Clear[mKeyFreeQ];
mKeyFreeQ[a_?AssociationQ, k_] := FreeQ[Keys[a], k, 1]
```

You could, in principle, replace the instance of `FreeQ` with `meuFreeQ`, too.

Per request, this can be written in the same type of recursive pattern the OPs `meuFreeQ` is written in:

```
Clear[recKeyFreeQ];
Options[recKeyFreeQ] = {SameTest -> SameQ};
recKeyFreeQ[assoc : <|fst_, ___|>, el_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[OptionValue[SameTest][First@fst, el], 
  False, 
  recKeyFreeQ[Rest@assoc, el, opt]] 
recKeyFreeQ[<||>, el_, OptionsPattern[]] := True
```

Comment: In this way is easy because you used the function `Keys`. Is there a way to do the same without using?

Comment: `KeyFreeQ[<|{1} -> 2|>, 1] =!= FreeQ[Keys@<|{1} -> 2|>, 1]`.

Comment: @Kuba that's a fair point. I added a level spec to `FreeQ` which corrects it.

Comment: @Mateus I added a recursive form similar to `meuFreeQ`.

Comment: `KeyFreeQ` and `Keys` also work on lists of rules (in addition to `Association`s). (+1)